# React-native flatlist not rendering?

Tags: javascript, react-native

My ReactNative FlatList is not rendering with this simple implementation.

```
 <FlatList style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'red'}}
           data = {this.state.users}
           keyExtractor={item => item.key.toString()}
           renderItem={({item}) => {
               return (
                   <ChatUserCard key={item.uid} username={item.username} />
               )
           }}
/>
```

#### ChatUserCard

```
<View style={styles.cardStyle}> 
    <Text style={styles.itemStyle}>{this.props.username}</Text>
    <Button style={styles.buttonStyle}
            title='Chat'
            onPress={this.startChat} />
</View>
```

Comment: Try without the return and the parentesis

Comment: i tried with just =>{<ChatUserCard key={item.uid} 
                                                     username={item.username}/>} but no luck

Comment: Are you using immutableJS?, Also, can you provide your entire class?

Answer (score 0):

Try add comments to the view below the flatlist and remove flex 1 from the styles on the flatlist. Try that to check if it is related with the styles

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking what's going on is that you've not wrapped your `FlatList` in a `View` that has `flex: 1` set. Also, you can probably use your `uid` as your key, rather than setting a `key` in your object data

#### Demo

https://snack.expo.io/@anonymoussb/so53688423

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';

class ChatUserCard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.cardStyle}> 
          <Text style={styles.itemStyle}>{this.props.username}</Text>
          <Button style={styles.buttonStyle}
                  title='Chat'
                  onPress={this.startChat} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        { key: 123, uid: 123, username: 'taco' },
        { key: 456, uid: 456, username: 'cat' }
      ]
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'red'}}
           data = {this.state.users}
           keyExtractor={item => item.key.toString()}
           renderItem={({item}) => {
               return (
                   <ChatUserCard key={item.uid} username={item.username} />
               )
           }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
});
```